# no se me ocurre como pedir a la función un valor del array

Tags: javascript

ejercicio:
escribí nuevamente la función medallaSegunPuesto, (si no la recordás la podés volver a ver en el ejercicio "Te vamos a dar un premio!" de la clase de Condicionales) pero esta vez usando como máximo un sólo if. Quizás los arrays te pueden ser útiles acá .

Por las dudas te recordamos que la función tiene que devolver la medalla que le corresponde a los primeros puestos de una competencia,

EJEMPLO:
medallaSegunPuesto(1)
"Oro"
medallaSegunPuesto(2)
"Plata"
medallaSegunPuesto(3)
"Bronce"
medallaSegunPuesto(4)
"Seguí participando"
medallaSegunPuesto(5)
"Seguí participando"

MI CODIGO;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola CESIAA, te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour] de bienvenida: Las preguntas con códgo deben añadirlo como texto para que sea fácil copiar y pegar a las respuestas y además sea legible desde móviles

Answer (score 1):

Solo necesitas agregar un parametro a la funcion :

```
 function medallaSegunPuesto(posicion){
     
     let puesto = ["oro" , "plata" , "bronce" , "segui participando"];
     //Comprobamos si la posicion coincide con alguna de las medallas , sino devolvemos "segui participando"
     if(posicion < 4){
        //rebajamos 1 a posicion para trabajar mejor con el array donde 1= oro , 2 plata , 3 bronce y 4 en adelante  segui participando
         return puesto[posicion-1];
     }else{
         return puesto[3];
     }
}
```

Luego para usar esta funcion :

```
medallaSegunPuesto(2); //esto devolveria plata
medallaSegunPuesto(10); // segui participando
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo considera evitar responder a preguntas mal formuladas. Las mismas terminan cerradas y tu respuesta y esfuerzo simplemente se pierden. Saludos